# Angular Lazy loading form (material) css not fully working

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

I am using angular(5.2.1) and material(5.2.1). I have developed some lazy loading modules which are working fine. But somehow the forms (user interface/css) are not fully working when I navigate by clicking on links.

But when I refresh the page then it works fine. I know I am missing something but can not figure out what..

Before refresh (by just navigating) 
[image]

After refreshing the page:
[image]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you create a working example?

Comment: how are you inserting the global material theme in your application?

Comment: in angular-cli.json like 
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
     "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
        ],

Comment: Solved it.. In some component's css and styles.css file I have included styles like ::ng-deep .mat-input-underline .mat-form-field directly and they were disturbing the behavior...... Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it..

In some component's css and styles.css file I have included styles like ::ng-deep .mat-input-underline, .mat-form-field directly and ::ng-deep .mat-input-underline and they were disturbing the behavior......

Thanks for responding.